# How to combine two image arrays into one RGB

Tags: python, image, multidimensional-array

I am working on a dataset that has two features, real and imaginary impedances. I applied data-to-image conversion using MTF in order to represent each one as an image (50x50). I was thinking of creating a 3-D image (50x50x2). I tried doing

```
Image = np.array([tag_gadf_re[0],tag_gadf_im[0]])
```

where `tag_gadf_re[0]` and `tag_gadf_im[0]` are the real and imaginary impedance image arrays. However, I tried saving the image using:

```
plt.imsave("Directory", Image)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Third dimension must be 3 or 4
```

Also note that the shape of `Image` is (2x50x50), when it should be (50x50x2). The solution seems simple, but I am a bit lost in the process. How can I combine both arrays appropriately and save the image, or do I need a 3rd layer in order to appropriately represent it as an RGB image?

Comment: Images are either 1d (grayscale), 3d (RGB) or 4d (e.g. PNGs with a transparent layer) but as far as I know there is no 2-channel representation so yes, you would need a thrid channel.

Comment: Please clarify whether the values you need to store are 8-bit/16-bit/32-bit integer or floating point.

Comment: @CrazyEngineer I understand. Am I able to create an empty third channel (50x50 array of zeros)? If so, how can I combine the three arrays now, since my current method produces a 2x50x50 shape, instead of the correct 50x50x2.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am not sure. Can you kindly explain how it matters so I can figure it out?

Comment: @Zelreedy: Before we discuss this any further: Do you have to save the values as an image? Wouldn't be a csv-file be a better solution?

Comment: @CrazyEngineer I am working on a ML project and am required to use CNN, that's why converting the data I have to images is necessary.

Comment: @Zelreedy: I don't know your data pipeline but if you have the data already as array, why bother saving it as image, only to reload and use it for training? Because to use it for a CNN, you have to convert the images back to an array (or something similar) anyway. Maybe it would help to elaborate on the whole process, where does your data come from? Why do you want to save it as an image? What will you do with the saved image later on? Maybe there is a more elegant solution. :)

Comment: @CrazyEngineer The concept is that I am using two different files, one for data-to-image conversion, and one for the CNN (where the images are loaded and fed into the model). The data-to-image conversion file should load the raw data, convert it to image, and save the image. The CNN file then loads the images and feeds them into the model. That's why my aim is to save the images from the first file and load them into the second one.

Comment: @Zelreedy: At least for me, that sounds unnecessarily complicated. Why not directly read the raw data, transform them if necessary, and feed them to the model? Otherwise you'll just occupy a lot of memory because you have the raw data and the image data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data as an image you need to be aware of its type and range so that you can choose an appropriate format. You also need to be aware of whether you can tolerate a *"lossy"* format which, when read, will not return identical values to those you stored.

---

If your data is integer and 16-bit or less, you can store it in a PNG. If it's multi-channel and 16-bit, you'll come unstuck with PIL. You can use `tifffile` though to store a 2-channel TIFF - maybe that can be greyscale + transparency or maybe 2 IFDs.

---

If your data is floating point, you pretty much have to use TIFF, PFM or EXR format. Again, `tifffile` can do this for you.

---

`tifffile` is [here](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/).

[wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/) can also do whatever `tifffile` can do.

---

Of course, you might choose to represent your two arrays/images as one above the other in a double-height image. It's your data.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I did `tag_gadf_re.dtype` to determine the type, and it's `float64`, which would mean I would need to use `tiffile` as you said. With regards to your last point, about representing the data as a double-height image, can you kindly elaborate or direct me to where I can learn more about this?

Comment: I was merely saying that you are presumably at liberty to store data however you like. So, instead of 50x50x2, you could use Numpy `np.vstack((real,imaginary))` to store a single channel image of 100x50 and divide it up into 2 channels yourself when you load it back in (i.e.. when you read it).